# psql (PostgreSQL client) tool install on RHEL

Tags: postgresql, psql, redhat, azure-postgres-database

I would like to install just the PostgreSQL client tool (psql) on RHEL on a container to connect to an Azure database for PostgreSQL server. Can you please point me step by step instructions on how to do the same?. I do not want to install the entire postgresql server

Comment: Doesn't Azure have a howto for that?   If not, are you sure an Azure database can be accessed from outside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On RedHat, and compatible systems, in order to install **just** the client only, the command is:

```
sudo yum install postgresql
```

or maybe `dnf`, but dnf may be Fedora? The above command installs only the client tools and their dependencies!

For a full-blown server install (should you require it in the future), the command is:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-server
```

You can back out either of the commands above by issuing the command:

```
sudo yum remove <package name>
```

i.e.

```
sudo yum remove postgresql
```

to uninstall your PostgreSQL client tools.

You **may** wish to consider a GUI:

- [`pgAdmin`](https://www.pgadmin.org/) an Open Source "sister project" to the main server one, very much tailored to PostgreSQL. Feature complete, but a bit resource heavy. Although the same could be said of Java clients...
- [OmniDB](https://omnidb.org/) I have not used it much, but have heard good things)
- JDBC

  - [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) - used a bit and liked
  - [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) - used a very small bit - similar to SQuirreL SQL
- Windows (if of interest to you for other machines/boot environments)

  - [HeidiSQL](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL) - used a little, fine. Very "bright and breezy" - a light, pleasant touch to it, if you have a Windows desk- or lap-top.

Unless you have a compelling reason not to use pgAdmin, I'd go with that first but you may have your own toolkit.

Comment: thanks. But i do not want the complete postgres server. I just want the client tools(psql). is there a way to just install connecting tools to query remote postgresql server?

Comment: Thank you Verace. that is clear

Answer (score 0):

Modern RHEL should have postgresql in a module.
If you need to install a spesific version you can use

`sudo yum install @postgresql:VER/client`
e.g.`sudo yum install @postgresql:20/client`